# Crypto module of HTML5 to RSA public encrypt

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, cryptography, rsa

How do encrypt with RSA using public key and PKCS padding, I have been trying to do this and am stuck on importing the key, so far I have this:

```
crypto.subtle.importKey('spki', key, {name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', hash: {name: 'SHA-256'}}, false, ['encrypt']).then(i => console.log(i)).catch(err => console.warn(err.message))
```

`key` is a key, of course, encoded using `TextEncoder`. This gives me an error `Cannot create a key using the specified key usages`.

I did importation and successful encryption/decryption for **AES-CBC** and wanted to do the same for RSA, any help will be highly appreciated.

**P.S.** I am trying not to use a library for this so this should be the last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "SSA" in "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5" stands for "Signature Scheme with Appendix", so it's a signature algorithm, and it can't be used with "encrypt" key usage.

The RSA encryption algorithm with PKCS#1 padding would be "RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5", but according to https://www.chromium.org/blink/webcrypto it's not supported ("*Chrome supported this in early days before Web Crypto was enabled by default, but has since dropped support."*). Here's more information about why it's not supported: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-webcrypto-algorithms-00#section-5 .

For RSA encryption in WebCrypto, it looks like the only supported padding is RSA-OAEP.

Comment: am now trying to use RSA-OAEP first to import key but am getting `DOMException`, my code is `crypto.subtle.importKey('spki', key, {name: 'RSA-OAEP', hash: {name: 'SHA-256'}}, false, ['encrypt']).then(i => console.log(i)).catch(err => console.warn(err.name, err.code, err.message))`, can you help me figure out what am doing wrong here? The key is already encoded with `TextEncoder`

Comment: i managed to figure this out, apparently, i was supposed to base64 decode the body part of the public key and convert the result to uint8array then use this in the import function